# Get the primary key value of an arbitrary entity in code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

Is there such a method?

```
object GetPrimaryKeyValue(DbEntityEntry entry);
```

Or how should it be implemented?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to cast your `DbContext` to `IObjectContextAdapter` so you can access the underlying `ObjectContext` which gives you access to some more advanced features hidden by `DbContext`.

Inside your class which derives `DbContext` the following method will work.

```
object GetPrimaryKeyValue(DbEntityEntry entry)
{
    var objectStateEntry = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.Entity);
    return objectStateEntry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;
}
```

If there is more than one key then you should iterate over the `EntityKeyValues` property.

Comment: That only works if the entity exists in the `ObjectStateManager`. Is there a way to get the entity key of a detached entry as well?

Comment: Im having the same problem. whenever i reference the ObjectStateManager i get this error. The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type 'NAME_OF_ENTITY'

Comment: @Shimmy, see my answer

Comment: @Hemslingo, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking to find the Primary Key of an entity. I am using Generics in my repository so I don't know the Entity until runtime. The only way I have found to do this so far is with a sql statement.

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : ApiController,IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{


    string sqlstr = @"
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
        WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + CONSTRAINT_NAME), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
        AND TABLE_NAME = '" + typeof(T).ToString() + "' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'";

    private Entities _entities = new Entities();


    public  virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        DbSqlQuery<T> queryTest = _entities.Set<T>().SqlQuery(sqlstr);
```

This is just a pratial of the full class but hopefully shows the solution I am using.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an attached `T item`. This may be long winded, but it works.

```
public object[] GetPrimaryKeyValues<T>(DbContext databaseContext, T item)
{
  return ((IObjectContextAdapter)databaseContext).ObjectContext.CreateEntityKey(typeof(T).Name.Pluralize(), item).EntityKeyValues.Select(kv => kv.Value).ToArray();
}
```

The return type is suitable to use in a `Find`, for example. See, the key values is actually an array of objects.

If you need Pluralize(), here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Atlas.Core.Kernel.Extensions
{
    public static class Strings
    {
      private static PluralizationService pluralizationService = PluralizationService.CreateService(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
      public static string Pluralize(this MemberInfo memberInfo)//types, propertyinfos, ect
      {
        return Pluralize(memberInfo.Name.StripEnd());
      }

      public static string Pluralize(this string name)
      {
        return pluralizationService.Pluralize(name); // remove EF type suffix, if any
      }



    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but I just saw this.

Heres How I did it (assumes pk is int)

```
public class Repository<T> : IDisposable, where T: class, new() 
{
    private int GetPrimaryKey(T item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return -1;

        using (var db = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            ObjectSet<T> set = (db as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
            string keyName = set.EntitySet
                .ElementType
                .KeyMembers
                .Select(x => x.Name)
                .First();
            Type type = typeof(T);
            int val = int.Parse(type.GetProperty(keyName).GetValue(item).ToString());
            return val;
        }
    }
}
```