# How can I get the Primary Key from a new TElement?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a generated class from an .edmx file:

```
public class User
{
    public int IDIsItMe { get; set; }
    public int IDOrMe { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a method to return the primary key.

```
public object GetPrimaryKey<T>(T element) where T: class
{
    // something
}
```

So if I do

```
var u = new User();
GetPrimaryKey(u);
```

I will get the primary key value.

How can I do that using Entity Framework 6?

Comment: I suggest you implement an interface on all your entities such as `public interface ObjectWithId { int Id {get;set;} }`, and add this as a constraint to `T`

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255089/get-the-primary-key-value-of-an-arbitrary-entity-in-code-first also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitykey.entitykeyvalues(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You say primary key as if it's always a single column.  A PK can be spanned across multiple columns.

Comment: @Ric an object is only an `EntityObject` when it is instantiate by DbContext

Comment: May I ask why you need the primary key? There may be other ways to achieve what you want to do with it without ever knowing the value. Also, as you may know, a new object won't have a final primary key value yet.